# What does shear mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, tensors

As I understand it, the gradient of a vector field can be decomposed into parts that relate to the divergence, curl, and shear of the function.  I understand what divergence and curl are (both computationally and geometrically), but what does shear mean in this context?  Is it related to the [shear mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) that is used in Linear Algebra?  What does it really mean and how do we use it?

Answer (score 28):

[image]

Consider a little block in the fluid with edge lengths $a,b,c$. Velocity at the origin is $\vec{v}=(u,v,w)$. With help of a Taylor series
expansion we can approximately write the velocity at $\vec{r} = (a,b,c)$ as:
$$
\vec{v}_P = \vec{v}(\vec{r}) = \vec{v}(a,b,c) \approx \vec{v}
 + \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x}a + \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial y}b + \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial z}c \\
= \vec{v} + \left(\vec{\nabla} \vec{v}\right)^T\vec{r} \quad \mbox{with} \quad \vec{r} = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$ \left(\vec{\nabla} \vec{v}\right) = \large \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix} $$
The gradient of the velocities $\left(\vec{\nabla} \vec{v}\right)$ can be split into a diagonal part,
a symmetric part (with zero trace) and an anti-symmetric part:
$$
\left(\vec{\nabla} \vec{v}\right) = \large \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix} \\
+ \large \begin{bmatrix} 0 &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)\\
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right) & 0 &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\right) \\
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right) &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right) &
0 \end{bmatrix} \\ + \large \begin{bmatrix} 0 &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right) \\
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right) & 0 &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\right) \\
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right) &
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right) &
0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The divergence (or dilatation) is recognized in the first matrix, the *trace* of that matrix to be precise. The rotation (curl) is recognized
in the third matrix. For the sake of completeness, put:
$$ \vec{\omega} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z \end{bmatrix} = \large \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix}
$$
then the vector representing rotation becomes:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \omega_z & -\omega_y \\ -\omega_z & 0 & \omega_x \\ \omega_y & - \omega_x & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \omega_y c - \omega_z b \\ \omega_z a - \omega_x c \\ \omega_x b - \omega_y a \end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2} \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}
$$
So the angular velocity of the fluid's rotation is half $\times\, \vec{\omega}$ .
But let's concentrate now on the *shear* (or distortion) part, as requested by the OP.
Consider one of the terms, take $\large \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$ ,
in two dimensions for simplicity.

[image]
During a time $dt$ a (square) fluid particle is transported in the plane. Then
$\large \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)$
is the velocity of the change of the two angles, as shown in the picture.
(Also notice that the angles, say $\phi$ , are very small, so $\,\tan(\phi) \approx \phi$ ) The fluid particle is deformed
herewith. Therefore the symmetric (traceless) matrix is also known as a *deformation tensor*. The deformation tensor contains *half* the
velocities of the deformation of a fluid particle.

EDIT.
At least that's what an old reader has teached us. But I'm not satisfied with the last picture. 
There must be a simpler way to look at it. Let's get rid of the partial derivatives in the first
place,
by employing [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) :
$$
\iint \left( \frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} \right) dx\,dy
= \oint \left( L\,dx + M\,dy \right)
$$
When specified for our three special cases, it reads:
$$ \begin{cases}
\mbox{divergence :} & \large \iint \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right) dx\,dy
= \oint \left( -v \,dx + u \,dy \right) \\
\mbox{curl :} & \large \iint \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) dx\,dy
= \oint \left( u \,dx + v \,dy \right) \\
\mbox{shear : } & \large \iint \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) dx\,dy
= \oint \left( - u \,dx + v \,dy \right) \end{cases}
$$
A picture says more than a thousand words:
[image]
Working out the shear part separately - performing vector addition $\,(\pm u,\pm v)\,dt\,$ - results in:
[image]

BONUS. Still let's have another look at it in some other, more "advanced" way : [**Lie series**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465315/how-to-derive-these-lie-series-formulas). 
A square (2-D) fluid particle is changed a little bit into an arbitrary quadrilateral, due to
velocity gradients, in general with a transformation $dT$ of the following sort:
$$
dT = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} dt
$$
If we assume that this transformation is occurring repeatedly, within a timespan $t$ , say $N$ times. Then $dt = t/N$ and:
$$
dT^N = \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \frac{t}{N}\right)^N
$$
The limit of this transformation for $N \to \infty$ is:
$$
T = \lim_{N\to\infty} dT^N = \Large e^{t \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}}
$$
In the main part of the current answer, we have split the general (infinitesimal) transformation
$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ into three parts, like this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & (b+c)/2 \\ (b+c)/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & (b-c)/2 \\ -(b-c)/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Let us consider the *accumulated effect* of each such transformations occuring repeatedly and separately.
Let $p=(b+c)/2$ and $\omega=(b-c)/2$ , both constant, then:
$$
\begin{cases}
D = \Large e^{t \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}} & \mbox{: divergence} \\
S = \Large e^{t \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p \\ p & 0 \end{bmatrix}} & \mbox{: shear} \\
\Omega = \Large e^{t \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \omega \\ -\omega & 0 \end{bmatrix}} & \mbox{: curl}
\end{cases}
$$
The well-known series expansion of $e^x$ will be employed for our purpose:
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} +
t \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix} +
\frac{1}{2} t^2 \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & 0 \\ 0 & d^2 \end{bmatrix} + \cdots = 
\begin{bmatrix} e^{ta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{td} \end{bmatrix}
$$
The result is a *scaling transformation*. The edges of the fluid square particle are enlarged with factors $e^{ta}$ and $e^{td}$ in x- and y- direction respectively. The total volume change is the determinant $e^{t(a+d)}$ , with $\;a+d = \partial u/\partial x+\partial v/\partial y$ .
$$
\Omega = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} +
(\omega t) \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
\frac{1}{2} (\omega t)^2 \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} +
\frac{1}{3!} (\omega t)^3 \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \cdots \\
= \begin{bmatrix} 1 - (\omega t)^2/2! + \cdots & (\omega t) - (\omega t)^3/3! + \cdots \\
- (\omega t) + (\omega t)^3/3! + \cdots & 1 - (\omega t)^2/2! + \cdots \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t) \\ -\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) \end{bmatrix}
$$
The result is a continuing *rotation*, with angular velocity $\omega$. 
Last but not least: **shear**.
$$
S = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} +
(p t) \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +
\frac{1}{2} (p t)^2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} +
\frac{1}{3!} (p t)^3 \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \cdots \\ = \mbox{in very much the same way}
= \begin{bmatrix} \cosh(p t) & \sinh(p t) \\ \sinh(p t) & \cosh(p t) \end{bmatrix}
$$
The result is a quadrilateral which has been (de)formed as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix} \cosh(p t) \\ \sinh(p t) \end{bmatrix} \quad ; \quad
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix} \sinh(p t) \\ \cosh(p t) \end{bmatrix}
$$
Make a simple sketch to see that this is indeed a *deformation*. The volume of the fluid particle is invariant under this transformation because of $$ \begin{vmatrix} \cosh(p t) & \sinh(p t) \\ \sinh(p t) & \cosh(p t) \end{vmatrix} = \cosh^2(p t) - \sinh^2(p t) = 1 $$

Comment: What is the name of the theorem / law that allows to decompose gradient field into diagonal, symmetric and anti-symmetric part?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: I think it would be better to write the gradient matrix as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{a+d}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{a+d}{2}
\end{pmatrix},$$
so that it looks like a scalar (proportional to the identity matrix), and have the shear be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{a-d}{2} & p \\
p & \frac{d-a}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $2p = b+c$, so that the shear contains *all* deformations while still being traceless (so the determinant of its exponentiation is still $1$).

In fact, this is what Oscar's decomposition looks like (and the usual way to do this decomposition).

Answer (score 8):

The decomposition is:

$\nabla_i v_j=\frac 12\varepsilon_{ijk}(\nabla\times v)_k+\frac 1n(\nabla\cdot v)\delta_{ij}+\left(\frac{\nabla_i v_j+\nabla_j v_i}{2}-\frac 1n(\nabla\cdot v)\delta_{ij}\right)$

The last term is the one we care about. It is symmetric and trace-free. Consider a basis in which it is diagonal. For example it could be $\mathop{diag}(-3,1,2)$. Imagine $v$ is the velocity field of a fluid. This term would represent fluid being compressed along the x-direction and spreading out in the y and z-directions (twice as much in the z-direction).

An example of a field, $v$, with no curl or divergence but with this last term being $\mathop{diag}(-3,1,2)$ would be $v=(-3x_1,x_2,2x_3)$.