# What is the determinant of exp(matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, lie-groups, determinant

Given a square matrix $A$, form the Lie series of it, which is defined by:
$$
e^A = I + A + \frac{1}{2} A^2 + \frac{1}{3!} A^3 + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!} A^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k
$$
Is there a simple expression for the *determinant* of $\,e^A$ ?

This question is motivated by:

- [What does shear mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196427/what-does-shear-mean/)

Where I've proved for the 2-D case:
$$
S = e^{\large t \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p \\ p & 0 \end{bmatrix}}
= \begin{bmatrix} \cosh(p t) & \sinh(p t) \\ \sinh(p t) & \cosh(p t) \end{bmatrix}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad \det(S) = 1
$$
I'd like to know if the determinant equals one for the 3-D case as well, where
$$\,S = \exp\left(t \begin{bmatrix} 0 & p & q \\ p & 0 & r \\ q & r & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out $\det(e^{A}) = e^{\text{tr}(A)}$.  I leave it as an exercise to prove.

Indeed, your last matrix also has determinant one.