# Decomposing a numerical Vector Field

Tags: vector-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, projection, numerical-calculus

I have $2$ sets of $3D-\text{Pointclouds}$ $P_1$ and $P_2$ (shown in Red and Blue respectively)  that lie on a common plane $(\text{Fig.} 1).$ The orientation of the plane  (with respect to origin) is known and is defined by a transformation matrix (Rotation and Translation) say $\mathbf{T}_0 = [\mathbf{R}_0| \mathbf{t}_0]$. Using the local coordinates of the points on the plane and $\mathbf{T}_0$, I can compute the global coordinates of each point in the pointcloud with respect to origin.

[image]
By connecting the elements from $P_2$ with its corresponding element in $P_1$ I obtain a vector field $\mathbf{V}$ which when projected in the $xy-$Plane appears as illustrated in the $\text{Fig.2}.$

**[EDIT]**

Since I don't know the scalar function that describes the vectorfield but only the coordinates of each vector  in the $xy$-plane, how can one split $\mathbf{V}$ into $3$ matrices:  a diagonal matrix, a [symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) (with zero trace) and an [anti-symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix)  as stated in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196427/what-does-shear-mean), which says

> [image: Blockquote]

I can describe my vector field as
$$
\mathbf{V} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{v}_{11} & \mathbf{v}_{12} & \dots & \mathbf{v}_{1N}\\
\mathbf{v}_{21} & \mathbf{v}_{22} & \dots & \mathbf{v}_{2N}\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots &  \vdots \\
\mathbf{v}_{M1} & \mathbf{v}_{12} & \dots & \mathbf{v}_{MN}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\mathbf{v}_{ij}$ is the vector from $i^\mathrm{th}$ row $(i \in 1,\dots,M)$ and $j^\mathrm{th}$ column $(j \in 1,\dots,N)$ whose $x$ and $y$ components are $u$ and $v$ respectively.

How do I proceed to decompose $\mathbf{V}$?