# How to compute the divergence of a measured vector field?

Tags: numerical-methods, vector-analysis, projective-geometry, divergence-theorem

The divergence a 2D vector Field $\mathbf{F}(x,y) = F_x(x,y)\, \hat{i} + F_y(x,y)\, \hat{j}$ is defined as
$$\mathrm{div}\,\mathbf{F} = \bigg( \dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} +  \dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}\bigg).$$
This can be calculated IF a function $\mathbf{F}(x,y)$ is given.

How do I compute the divergence if I don't know the function $\mathbf{F}(x,y)$ that describes my vector field but rather I have an array of numbers (noisy) that form a  vector field as depicted below.

[image]

I know only the $(x,y)$ coordinates  of the tip and the tail of each vector. Just by looking at the picture below, the field has a negative divergence. How can one calculate the divergence of such a field?

---

Note: This is a part of the problem  addressed  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846278/find-the-divergence-and-curl-of-a-numerical-vector-field)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: Since you know your data is "noisy", it makes sense to try *smoothing* it before trying to do numerical differentiation.  A typical approach (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter)) is to fit a polynomial to local data points, much like a moving average.  It is fortunate that you do not need more than first (partial) derivatives to estimate divergence.

Comment: Is smoothing done to make the field differentiable? How do I algebraically express the divergence equation  in this case for 2 point clouds each with $M\times N$ entries of  the coordinates?

Comment: As you can guess from the picture, the points are moving further away along $z-$axis.  If it were to move towards the observer, the vectors would  point outwards. My goal is to first find the divergence and using it find the translation amount along $z-$axis. Then translate the points (by the amount from divergence) such that the field vanishes.

Comment: You described the array of numbers as noisy, and numerical differentiation will amplify that noise.  Thus smoothing is suggested as a means of mitigating the noisiness of your data.  Experimentation is needed to see if results that suit your application are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the divergence theorem to approximate the divergence and prevent noise from ruining your approximation.

We have $$\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \int_A (\text{div} \mathbf{F}) dA$$ where the left hand side integral is over the boundary $C$ of any sufficiently nice set $A$ and the right hand side integral is over the set $A$.

Now consider a small area $A$ surrounding the point $p$ and assume that you know $\mathbf{F}$ at some points $q_i$ of $C$. You can then approximate the left integral using the a weighted sum of the $\mathbf{F}(q_i)$. The integral on the right is approximately $ A \text{div} \mathbf{F}(p)$.

Your graph suggests that you know $\mathbf{F}$ on a uniform grid with square cells. For each cell with corners $a_i$ you can find a new cell such that $a_i$ marks the middle of the $i$th edge of the new cell and the outward normal is well defined at $a_i$. You need to rotate 45 degrees to get the new cell. Use the new cell to compute an approximation for the divergence at the center of the new cell.

Comment: To make things more general and simplify things I created $\mathbf{F}$ on a uniform grid. In reality my measured data $(\mathbf{F})$ is non-uniformaly spaced.  I am somewhat overwhelmed by the literatures  on dealing with vector field on non-uniform grid. How do I compute the divergence if the grid is non-uniform? Any recommendations of books or papers on this subject? Thanks!!! : )

Comment: @unfinished_sentenc This is outside my area of expertise, I cannot give you good references.