# Formal Power Series as Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, power-series, formal-power-series

Let $t^k$ act as the $k$-th derivative operator on the set of polynomials.  So

$$t^k(x^n)=t^k x^n=(n)_kx^{n-k}$$

where $(n)_k=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)$ is the falling factorial.  Then with a formal power series, $f(t)=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k\frac{t^k}{k!}$, the linear operator $f(t)$ acts as such that

$$f(t)(x^n)=f(t)x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k x^{n-k}$$

Therefore, depending on the coefficients of the power series, we can get some interesting binomial identites.  For example, if $f(t)=e^{yt}$, since the coefficients $a_n=y^n$, we get

$$e^{yt}x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}y^k x^{n-k}=(x+y)^n$$

by linearity,

$$(e^{yt}-1)x^n=(x+y)^n-x^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}y^k x^{n-k}$$

and perhaps not as obvious

$$\left(\frac{e^{yt}-1}{t}\right)x^n=\int_{x}^{x+y}u^ndu$$

Now suppose that $f(t)=e^{yt}-1-yt$.  Then

$$(e^{yt}-1-yt)x^n=(x+y)^n-x^n-ynx^{n-1}=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}y^k x^{n-k}$$

Obviously there is a nice formed forward difference equation in the previous case that is not happening here.  But there is a relationship with subtracted terms of the binomial expansion.  What i would really like help understanding is whether or not a possible analogous integral representation exists for the following operator:

$$\left(\frac{e^{yt}-1-yt}{t^2}\right)x^n=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{y^{k+2}}{(k+2)(k+1)}\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{y^{k+2}}{(k+1)(k+2)}x^{n-k}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+2}{k+2}\frac{y^{k+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}x^{n-k}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\binom{n+2}{k}y^kx^{n+2-k}$$

It is not as simple.  Clearly $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x^{n+2}}{((n+2)(n+1)}$.  If I integrated below I think the math is correct

$$\int_x^{x+y}{\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}}du=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=1}^{n+2}\binom{n+2}{k}y^kx^{n+2-k}$$

Which is really close, but the lower bound on the summation is $1$, not $2$.  Does any one have any insight in how i can fix this, if possible?

Comment: did you try rewriting everything in term of convolution products ? $D g = \delta' \ast g$ and $D^ {-1} g = 1_{x > 0} \ast  g$

Comment: The reason it is in $t$ is that the above comes from Umbral Calculus.  Here, $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all formal power series in $t$ over an arbitrary field $F$ with characteristic 0.  That is why it is in $t$.

Comment: The usual notation is $f(t) = \sum_{k\ge 0} c_k t^k\implies f(D) g =(\sum_{k\ge 0} c_k D^k) g$, compatible with the holomorphic functional calculus and things like this

Comment: Can you elaborate more with references as well?

Comment: Umbral Calculus? Hmm, I wonder if that is not just a re-invention of [Heaviside’s Operator Calculus](http://myreckonings.com/wordpress/2007/12/07/heavisides-operator-calculus/) in other wordings.

Comment: That's the impression I've got from trying to understand the question. But upon reading the [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus), I now see that Umbral calculus is quite a different kind of thing.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus), umbral calculus works by _pretending that indices are exponents_.
I may be blind, but I don't see this moving subscripts to superscripts and vice versa anywhere in the question, nor in the accepted answer.
So may I ask what's the big deal about umbral calculus in this specific case?

Comment: There is more of you consider the action of a linear functional as opposed to an operator. It helps to rigorously define how the transformation from index to exponent occurs.

Comment: The idea is to define $\langle f(t)\mid x^n\rangle =a_n$.  Then you can consider the action of say, for example, $$\langle e^{yt} \mid x^n\rangle=y^n$$ so this relates the index to the exponent here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note:* OPs calculations are quite ok and it shows the operators are closely related, but different. I don't think there is a necessity to *fix* anything.

I skimmed through the classic *[The Umbral Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486441393)* by Steven Roman, but there was no indication that something more is going on regarding OPs question. Another source I've checked without success was *[The Calculus of Finite Differences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0828400334)* by C. Jordan.

It might be helpful to list a few higher powers of the operators under consideration.

In the following I use OPs notation which is precisely the same used by Steven Roman.

> **Translation operator: $e^{yt}$**
>
> Since this operator satisfies:
>   \begin{align*}
> e^{yt}x^n&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}t^kx^n
> =\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{y^k}{k!}(n)_kx^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}y^kx^{n-k}\\
> &=(x+y)^n
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(e^{yt}\right)^2 x^n=e^{yt}(x+y)^n=(x+2y)^n
> \end{align*}
>   and in general for $j\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> e^{jyt}x^n=(x+jy)^n
> \end{align*}

Since $x^n, n\geq 0$ form a basis of the vector space of all polynomials $p$ in a single variable $x$ and the translation operator is linear, we obtain
\begin{align*}
e^{jyt}p(x)=p(x+jy)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

hence the name *translation operator*.

> **Forward difference operator: $e^{yt}-1$**
>
> Here we obtain for polynomials $p$ using (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left(e^{yt}-1\right)p(x) = p(x+y)-p(x)
> \end{align*}

The next one is

> **Operator: $\frac{\exp(yt)-1}{t}$**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{e^{yt}-1}{t}\right)x^n&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k!}t^{k-1}x^n\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{y^k}{k!}(n)_{k-1}x^{n-(k-1)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}y^kx^{n+1-k}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\left((x+y)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\int_x^{x+y}u^n\,du
> \end{align*}
>
> Similarly we obtain from (2) by linearity
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{e^{yt}-1}{t}\right)^2x^n
> &=\left(\frac{e^{yt}-1}{t}\right)\frac{1}{n+1}\left((x+y)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{n+1}\left[\frac{1}{n+2}\left((x+2y)^{n+2}-(x+y)^{n+2}\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\left.-\frac{1}{n+2}\left((x+y)^{n+2}-x^{n+2}\right)\right]\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left((x+2y)^{n+2}-2(x+y)^{n+1}+x^{n+2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n+2)_2}\left(\int_{x+y}^{x+2y}u\, du-\int_x^{x+y}u\,du\right)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Here at (2) and (3) we can see quite nicely how the operator $\frac{\exp(yt)-1}{t}$ is connected with the integral operator. It can be extended to higher powers without too much effort and the relationship with the integral operator looks plausible.

> **Operator: $\frac{\exp(yt)-1-t}{t^2}$**
>
> Now we take  a look at the operator which is on the focus of OP and its generalisation.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{e^{yt}-1-t}{t^{2}}\right)x^n
> &=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{y^k}{k!}t^{k-2}x^n\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{y^{k}}{k!}(n)_{k-2}x^{n-(k-2)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n+2)_2}\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n+2}{k}y^kx^{n+2-k}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(n+2)_2}\left((x+y)^{n+2}-x^{n+2}-nyx^{n+1}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing the final expression with (3) we do not see a plausible representation via integrals since the term $nyx^{n+1}$ don't provide anything nicely of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{integrated expression (end point) - integrated expression (starting point)}
> \end{align*}

This impression becomes more strongly  when looking at  the general case. We obtain for $j\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{e^{yt}-1-\frac{t^2}{2}-\cdots-\frac{t^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}}{t^j}\right)x^n
&=\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{y^k}{k!}t^{k-j}x^n\\
&=\frac{1}{(n+j)_j}\sum_{k=j}^\infty\binom{n+j}{k}y^kx^{n+j-k}\\
&=\frac{1}{(n+j)_j}\left((x+y)^{n+j}-\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\binom{n+j}{k}y^kx^{n+j-k}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: I upvoted... I just haven't voted for the 50 yet...

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Many thanks for your friendly comment! Regards,

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)

Comment: No problem.  I was glad to see your answer and I have been looking at general cases as you did above.  I had the feeling the analogous integral expression may have been a far stretch, but there is still a nice relationship regardless.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: Thanks, you're welcome and I agree with your impression. I strongly recommend to go through Steven Romans small booklet  *umbral calculus* as it provides a lot of related interesting information.

Answer (score 3):

Introductionary reference:

- [Operator Calculus](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/examples.htm)

So why not replace $\,t\,$ by the differential operator $\,d/dx\,$ everywhere it occurs? Next reference:

- [Exponential of a function times derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719487/exponential-of-a-function-times-derivative)

Therefore we have in general and especially:
$$
e^{y\,d/dx} f(x) = f(x+y) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad e^{y\,d/dx} x^n = (x+y)^n
$$
Indeed the operator $1/(d/dx)$ is the inverse of differentiation, which is integration. So let's take a look at your *perhaps not as obvious* expression:
$$
\left(\frac{e^{y\,d/dx}-1}{d/dx}\right)x^n=\frac{1}{d/dx}\left(e^{y\,d/dx}-1\right)x^n\\
=\int\left[(x+y)^n - x^n\right] dx = \frac{(x+y)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C
$$
with $C$ an arbitrary constant. Evaluation is not ambiguous, because the operators $1/(d/dx)$ and $\left(e^{y\,d/dx}-1\right)$ do indeed *commute*. Which
means that we can do algebra with *these* operators as with common numbers. The same in, last but not least:
$$
\left(\frac{e^{y\,d/dx}-1-y\,d/dx}{(d/dx)^2}\right)x^n=\int\left\{\int\left[(x+y)^n-x^n\right]dx\right\}dx-\int y\,x^n\,dx
\\=\frac{(x+y)^{n+2}-x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{y\,x^{n+1}}{n+1} + Cx + D
$$
with $C$ and $D$ arbitrary constants. This result is deviant from your last formula. It is noticed that:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left[\frac{(x+y)^{n+2}-x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{y\,x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C\,x + D\right]
= (x+y)^n - x^n - y\frac{dx^n}{dx}
$$
EDIT. I almost forgot to mention the stuff where it's all about: the *formal power series*
([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)).
$$
(y+x)^{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}y^{n-k}x^{k} \quad \Longrightarrow \\
\frac{(x+y)^{n+2}-x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{y\,x^{n+1}}{n+1} =\\
\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[\sum _{k=0}^{n+2}{n+2 \choose k}y^{k}x^{n+2-k} - x^{n+2} - (n+2)y\,x^{n+1}\right]=\\
\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[\sum _{k=2}^{n+2}{n+2 \choose k}y^{k}x^{n+2-k}
+ {n+2 \choose 0}y^0 x^{n+2} - x^{n+2} + {n+2 \choose 1}y^1 x^{n+1} - (n+2)y\,x^{n+1} \right]\\
=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[\sum _{k=2}^{n+2}{n+2 \choose k}y^{k}x^{n+2-k}\right]
$$
So here is your fix on the lower bound of the summation.