# Exponential of a function plus a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, operator-theory, exponentiation

The exponential of a derivative is the shift operator
$e^{a\partial} f(x)=f(a+x)$. I wander if there exists a compact expression for the action of the operator
\begin{equation}
e^{g(x)+a\partial} f(x)=?
\end{equation}

Possible ways that I thought to find the answer are 1) Explicitely by expanding the Taylor series and resumming different classes of terms, or 2) Via a generalization of the solution provided in this post [Exponential of a function times derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719487/exponential-of-a-function-times-derivative) (see the last comment there).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you Tyma. The first step in your proposed solution doesn't wor because the derivativa and $g(x)$ do not commute.

Answer (score 1):

After an explicit resummation, guesses and checks, I found the following compact relation:
\begin{equation}
f^{g(x)+a\partial}f(x)=e^{G(x+a)-G(x)}f(x+a)\,,
\end{equation}
where,
\begin{equation}
G(x)=\int g(x) dx \,.
\end{equation}
However I was not able to prove this more abstractly.