# Convergence of Lie Series

Tags: taylor-expansion, lie-algebras, exponentiation, differential-operators, lie-derivative

In the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719487/exponential-of-a-function-times-derivative) question the Lie Series result
$$
  \boxed{ \; e^{t \phi(x) \frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = f\left(e^{t \phi(x) \frac{d}{dx}} x\right) \; }
$$
was mentioned. Now for $f(x)$ analytic and when $\phi(x)$ is a polynomial, this result makes sense.

Now for an arbitrary smooth $\phi(x)$ one can do a coordinate transformation (assume its one-one onto and therefore invertible)
$$
s(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x}\phi(x')dx'
$$
and get the result
$$
e^{t \frac{d}{ds}}g(s) = g(s+t) = f(s^{-1}(s(x) +t))
$$

But now if I were to do a series expansion,
$$
e^{t \frac{d}{ds}}g(s) = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\left[ \frac{d}{ds}\right]^n g(x)
$$
and convert the series back to the original coordinates I get the series
$$
e^{t \phi(x) \frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\left[ \phi(x) \frac{d}{dx}\right]^n f(x)
$$
where I have used the relation
\begin{align}
\frac{ds}{dx} &= \phi \\
\frac{d}{ds} &= \frac{dx}{ds}\frac{d}{dx}
\end{align}
and used the result
$$
\frac{dx}{ds} = \left( \frac{ds}{dx}\right)^{-1}
$$
asuming $s(x)$ is invertible.

But this series seems to be divergent as the number of terms coming from the successive derivatives on $\phi$ in the $n$th series term grows asymptotically as $\sim \exp\left\{2^nlog(2)\right\}$.

In fact, if I were to Taylor expand the function $x(s)$ at $s=0$ as
\begin{align}
x(s) &= x_{0} + \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{ds} \Bigg |_{s = 0}\frac{s^n}{n!} \\
&=x_{0} + \sum_{1}^{\infty} \left[ \phi(x) \frac{d}{dx}\right]^{n-1}(\phi(x)) \Bigg |_{x = x_0}\frac{s^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{s\phi(x)\frac{d}{dx}} x \Bigg |_{x = x_0}
\end{align}
This also seems to have the same divergence issue.

**If this was indeed Taylor expandable shouldn't it have been convergent?**

**How did the changing of coordinates change the convergence properties of the series?**

**Is there a more general condition on $\phi(x)$ for such a series to be convergent than it is a polynomial?**

PS: Please forgive the abuse of notation.